# Convert ScrollView with condition to Flatlist

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I need to convert this scrollView to a flatlist, but is completely stuck, due to the fact that i didnt write the code myself.

matchesRound is a list, but i cant seem to figure out profile contains when we map it, i thought that i could just make a const from matchesRound and use that as data in the flatlist?

```
<ScrollView
                        {!user.settings.hidden &&
                            matchesRound
                                .sort((a, b) => {
                                    const aLength = a.relation.questions.length;
                                    const bLength = b.relation.questions.length;
                                    if (aLength === 0 && bLength > 0) return -1;
                                    if (aLength > 0 && bLength === 0) return 1;
                                    if (aLength === 0 && bLength === 0)
                                        return b.relation.updatedAt - a.relation.updatedAt;
                                    const aLastQuestion = a.relation.questions[aLength - 1];
                                    const bLastQuestion = b.relation.questions[bLength - 1];
                                    const aHasAnswered =
                                        !!aLastQuestion[user.id] && !aLastQuestion[getOtherUserId(a.relation, user.id)];
                                    const bHasAnswered =
                                        !!bLastQuestion[user.id] && !bLastQuestion[getOtherUserId(b.relation, user.id)];
                                    if (!aHasAnswered && bHasAnswered) return -1;
                                    if (aHasAnswered && !bHasAnswered) return 1;
                                    return aLastQuestion.time - bLastQuestion.time;
                                })
                                .map((profile, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <>
                                            {i == 0 && <View style={{ width: 6 }} />}
                                            <GameCard
                                                key={i + "profile"}
                                                superDM={!!getUserStatus(profile.relation, user.id).superDM}
                                                prime={getUserStatus(profile.relation, user.id).thanksToPrime}
                                                profile={profile}
                                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Rounds", { profile: profile })}
                                            />
                                        </>
                                    );
                                })}
                        {(matchesRound.length === 0 || user.settings.hidden) &&
                            [0, 1, 2].map(key => (
                                <>
                                    {key == 0 && <View style={{ width: 6 }} />}
                                    <GameCardEmpty key={key + "gameCards"} />
                                </>
                            ))}
                    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to sort your array somewhere else (like in useEffect) and then simply use your FlatList like this

```
<FlatList
data={matchesRound}
renderItem={(profile) => {
    return(
        <GameCard
            key={profile.index + "profile"}
            superDM={!!getUserStatus(profile.item.relation, user.id).superDM}
            prime={getUserStatus(profile.item.relation, user.id).thanksToPrime}
            profile={profile}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Rounds", { profile: profile.item })}
        />
    )
}}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
ListEmptyComponent={() => <GameCardEmpty />}
ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{marginBottom: 5}}></View>}
/>
```